# MySQL: How to use implode array in WHERE IN clause of MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem when I try to use implode array in `WHERE IN` clause and display it. Some of the record in the database has an apostrophe in it.
Example the data in my database are `testing`,`test'ing`,`tes't`. And my code below is how I implode the data to be used in `WHERE IN` clause.

```js
<?php 
$arr = array();
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sampleTxt FROM Table")or die(mysqli_error($con));
while(list($txt) = mysqli_fetch_row($qry)){
  $t = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$txt);
  $arr[] = "'".$t."'";
  }
$sampl = implode(',',$arr);
?>
```

And here is my sample code on how I used it on `WHERE IN` clause.

```js
<?php
$qry2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sampleTxt2 FROM Table2 WHERE sampleTxt IN (".$sampl.")")or die(mysqli_error($con));
while(list($txt2) = mysqli_fetch_row($qry2)){
  echo $txt2;
  }
?>
```

The output should be

> testing
> test'ing
> tes't

but instead the output is just the `testing`.

Comment: can you a var_dump($sampl) and share the output??

Comment: Show the result of `print_r($t);`?

Comment: `$t` is not an array.

Comment: but if I'm gonna print `print_r($arr)`, the result is `Array ( [0] => 'testing' [1] => 'test\'ing' [2] => 'tes\'t' ) `

Comment: if I'm gonna echo `$sampl`, the result is <code> 'testing','test\'ing','tes\'t' </code>

Comment: Why don't you use a simple join? `SELECT sampleTxt2 FROM Table2 JOIN Table ON table2.sampleTxt = Table.sampleTxt`

Answer (score 0):

Check for below code

```
<?php 
$arr = array();
$qry = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sampleTxt FROM Table")or die(mysqli_error($con));
while(list($txt) = mysqli_fetch_row($qry)){
  //$t = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$txt);
  $arr[] = '"'.$txt.'"';
  }
$sampl = implode(',',$arr);
?>
```

And then

```
<?php
$qry2 = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT sampleTxt2 FROM Table2 WHERE sampleTxt IN ('.$sampl.')')or die(mysqli_error($con));
while(list($txt2) = mysqli_fetch_row($qry2)){
  echo $txt2;
  }
?>
```